# AlertDialog in custom Hashmap array adapter

Tags: android, listview, hashmap

I am creating a custom Hash map array adapter.In that,when the user clicks on an element, an AlertDialog pops up,in that user can see his messaages,
For this I am using this code,

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);



    alert.setTitle("PassWord Protected Message");
            alert.setMessage("Please Enter The Password to See The Messages");

            // Set an EditText view to get user input 
            final EditText input = new EditText(this);
            alert.setView(input);

            alert.setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) 
            {
        //  Editable value = input.getText();
             // Do something with value!
                String we=input.getText().toString();
            //  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), we, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();
                if (we.equalsIgnoreCase("password"))
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n"); 
                        String sender = splitted[0];

                        for ( int i = 1; i < splitted.length; ++i )
                        {
                           //some code here
                        }

                    } 
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }

            }
            });

            alert.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                 // Canceled.
            }
            });

             alert.show();
```

This `AlertDialog` will ask user to enter a password.Then user will be able to see the messages.
But I am getting error ,

```
String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).split("\n");
```

In this,I am getting error on split function and the error is "The method split(String) is undefined for the type HashMap".

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html. split method is for string.

Comment: My custom adapter for the list view is having hashmap array to put the string according to the key.That is why i am getting error on this because ultimately this view will also be shown into that same list view..

Comment: i guess it should be String mystring = smsList.get( pos ).get("key");mystring.split("\n")

Comment: @user2208690 : try it as :`String[] splitted = smsList.get( pos ).toString().split("\n");`  if HashMap values as Strings

Comment: @user2208690 can you show us how you defined smsList. is it a arraylist or hashmap?

Comment: @Raghunandan helpful work..got the idea..

Comment: @user2208690 List<HashMap<String,String>> smsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>(); Is your smsList something like this?. if it is then what i posted in comment will work probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to type cast the smsList to `String`

```
String[] splitted = ((String)smsList.get( pos )).split("\n");
```